# mv multiple directories into the same directories

Tags: bash, directory, mv

I want to move multiple directories to the directories if the second directory exist.

Initial:

```
dmv/toto/toto0
dmv/toto1/toto1
dmv/toto2/toto2

dmv/toto0/toto00
dmv/toto2/toto02
```

Final:

```
dmv/toto/toto0
dmv/toto1/toto1
dmv/toto2/toto2

dmv2/toto0/toto00
dmv2/toto0/toto0
dmv2/toto2/toto02
dmv2/toto2/toto2
```

I try this, but I don't check if a directory exist:

```
~/dmv/$ for i in $(ls); do mv "${i}"/* ../dmv2/"${i}"; done
```

Comment: Welcome to UNIX&Linux SE. Can you please edit your question to include an actual question or what your problem is, any errors you have received, etc?

Comment: What directories, if any, existed under `dvm2/` at the initial stage?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial and final directory listing stages are somewhat cryptic, and so I am not sure about what you ask for exactly.  Perhaps this will help you a bit. A script tends to be more readable; call it `mvDir.sh` for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
for file in ./*; do
    [ -d "${file}" ] && [ mkdir -p ../dmv2/"${file}" ] \
    && mv "${file}"/* ../dmv2/"${file}" 
done
```

Make sure that:

- the place where your script's path is included in your `PATH` environment variable. On cli, do: `$ echo "$PATH"`) to check it.
- the script is executable. On cli, do:  `$ chmod u+x mvDir.sh`

To run it just go to the directory that contains the script and the directories whose names you want to parse, and on cli, do: `$ ./mvDir.sh`

If you insist on an awkwardly long one-liner, do in cli:

```
$ for file in ./*; do [ -d "${file}" ] && [ mkdir -p ../dmv2/"${file}" ] && mv "${file}"/* ../dmv2/"${file}"; done
```

There are other, more advanced ways of doing this, e.g. involving `find`.